# How to read Model values and send them by ajax post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code and it`s pointing out errors as follows

> Error 1   The name 'date' does not exist in the current context
>   Error 2   The name 'person' does not exist in the current context

What is wrong?

```
 $("#test").Click(function () {
            var date = $("#DateFrom").val();
            var person = Model.SelectedPerson;

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("testEmp","Employee",new {dateFrom = date, selectedPerson= person})',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#text).html(result);
                },
                              });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ date: '..', person: '...' }),
    success: function(result) {           
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: Take a look at this answer for the complete solution.
[jquery ajax forms for ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994032/jquery-ajax-forms-for-asp-net-mvc-3)