# Calling controller from view, passing input text fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I have two text inputs, content of which needs to be passed to a certain action as parameters when a button is clicked. I'm using MVC3
View:

```
<input name="input2" type="text"  class="inputfield" id="datepicker_1" /></td>
<input name="input2" type="text"  class="inputfield" id="datepicker_2" /></td>

@Html.Action("Search", ...)
```

Controller:
    public ActionResult Search(...)
I suppose the object routeValues or RouteValueDictionary should be used in the @Html.Action for this. These object are confusing for me a bit. Could anyone clarify this for me please. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is confusing for me a bit. Could you please clarify you question? I mean, what exactly is your problem? Do you mean passing que parameters to the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Html.Action will probably generate the link html before you provide the inputs. You need to either place your inputs inside a form to be submited to your action, or use ajax, with jquery perhaps, to call the action, like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAction" }))
{
    <input name="datepicker_1" type="text"  class="inputfield" id="datepicker_1" /></td>
    <input name="datepicker_2" type="text"  class="inputfield" id="datepicker_2" /></td>
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Datetime datepicker_1, Datetime datepicker_2) {...}
```

For an Ajax example, check this question:

[jquery ajax forms for ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994032/jquery-ajax-forms-for-asp-net-mvc-3)

Hope this helps...

Comment: @mishap be carefull  these 2 line must be inside this block
using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAction" }))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need have a submit on your view, and then implement a post action on your controller, to handle the submit. I.e. something along the lines of

```
 <input type="submit" value="Search..." />
```

in the view, and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
```

the parameters depend on whether your view is strongly typed. The above assumes its not.